# Is it Possible to Use ED25519 Instead of RSA When Logging Into a Remote App Engine Instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssh, app-engine-flexible, ed25519

When a Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) user executes:

```sh
gcloud app instances ssh \
$AEF_INSTANCE_ID \
--project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME \
--service $AEF_APP_SERVICE_NAME \
--version $AEF_APP_VERSION_NAME

#=>

WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
. . .
```

for the first time, an RSA key is generated:

```sh
ls -1 ~/.ssh/google_compute_*

#=>

google_compute_engine
google_compute_engine.pub
google_compute_known_hosts
```

Is it possible at this time to use ED25519 instead of RSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

At this time, it is **not** possible to use an ED25519-based key instead of an RSA-based key when logging into a running App Engine Flexible Environment (AEF) instance.

In other words, if you were to:

1. delete the old RSA key:

   ```sh
   rm ~/.ssh/google_compute_*
   ```
2. generate an ED25519 key:

   ```sh
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)

   #=>

   Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
   . . .
   ```

   **Note**: use an *absolute* path when prompted for a key file name and location; using a *relative* path returns the following error:

   > Saving key "~/.ssh/google_compute_engine" failed: No such file or directory
3. and attempt to log into a running App Engine Flexible Environment (AEF) instance:

   ```sh
   gcloud app instances ssh \
   $AEF_APP_INSTANCE_ID \
   --project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME \
   --service $AEF_APP_SERVICE_NAME \
   --version $AEF_APP_VERSION_NAME
   ```

you **will** get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.instances.ssh) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid SSH key "$(whoami):ssh-ed25519 $ED25519_PUBLIC_KEY $(whoami)". Expected "[USERNAME]:ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] [USERNAME]" or [USERNAME]:ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] google-ssh {"userName":"[USERNAME]","expireOn":"[EXPIRE_TIME]"}.
>
> If expiration time is being specified, please refer to RFC3339 for correct format.

However, you can find an active feature request for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195231191).